# Why am I getting Internal Server Error when I'm using Flask?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, internal-server-error

I'm currently working on my machine learning svm_hog model. Now I want to connect my model to my flask. However, everytime I click on the prediction button on my webpage, it brings me to a page that says Internal Server Error. My model works just fine, and I think the problem is in my Flask code but I still get error until now. Below is the code that I use, to run the flask.

flask.py :

```
import os
from app import app
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog  
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def predictThis(folder_path):
    from keras.models import load_model
    import numpy as np
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    from numpy import argmax

    model = load_model("HOG_SVM.npy")
    img_width,img_height=550,293
    abnormalities = {0:"normal", 1:"abnormal"}
    test_image = image.load_img(folder_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=0)
    result = model.predict(test_image)

    category_result = argmax(result)
    return abnormalities[category_result]

app = Flask(__name__)

#flask routing
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/start")
def start():
    return render_template("start.html")

@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
        if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
        
        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
                flash('No image selected for uploading')
                return redirect(request.url)
            
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join('static/upload', filename))
                #print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
                #flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')

                result = predictThis('static/upload/' + filename)
                if result == 'normal':
                        train = "NORMAL CHEST X RAY"
                elif result == 'abnormal':
                        train = "TUBERCULOSIS CHEST X-RAY"
                        
                return render_template('start.html', output=train, filename=filename)
        else:
                flash('Allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
                return redirect(request.url)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    #print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='upload/' + filename), code=301)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My ml model code (HOG_SVM.npy):

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skimage import color
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import glob
from sklearn import metrics
from PIL import Image 
from numpy import *

# define parameters of HOG feature extraction
orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = (8, 8)
cells_per_block = (2, 2)
threshold = .3

dataset_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Train" # The path of dataset

# Read the image files:
category_im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path) # Read all the files in the path
num_category_im = size(category_im_listing) # States the total no. of category
print("There are " + str(num_category_im) + " categories") # Prints the number value of the no.of categories dataset
data= []
labels = []
count = 0

# compute HOG features and label them:
for category in category_im_listing: # Enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img = Image.open(dataset_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
        img = img.resize((150,150))
        gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel 
        # calculate HOG for positive features
        fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True) # fd= feature descriptor
        data.append(fd)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1

# encode the labels, converting them from strings to integers
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)

# Partitioning the data into training and testing splits, using 80%
# of the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
print(" Constructing training/testing split...")
(trainData, testData, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(np.array(data), labels, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

#%% Train the linear SVM
print(" Training Linear SVM classifier with HOG...")
model = svm.LinearSVC(multi_class='ovr')
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels)

#%% Evaluate the classifier
print(" Evaluating classifier on test data ...")
predictions = model.predict(testData)
print(classification_report(testLabels, predictions))
print("Validation Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(testLabels, predictions))

# Save the model:
joblib.dump(model, 'HOG_SVM.npy')
```

start.html :

```
<form method="post" action="/start" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% if filename %}
                <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}" width="250" height="290">
                <label for="actual-btn" class="center">{{output}}</label> 
                {% else %}
                <input class="center" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Classify" cass="btn">
                {% endif %} </form>
```

Update: I modified the app.run() line in the flask.py code into app.run(debug=True) and it shows me this

```
  * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3426: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

And after I run the %tb, it shows me this

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-869c29e262d1> in <module>
      1 if __name__=='__main__':
----> 2     app.run(debug=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
    988 
    989         try:
--> 990             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    991         finally:
    992             # reset the first request information if the development server

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
   1048         from ._reloader import run_with_reloader
   1049 
-> 1050         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
   1051     else:
   1052         inner()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
    337             reloader.run()
    338         else:
--> 339             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
    340     except KeyboardInterrupt:
    341         pass

SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: There should be exception traces in the Flask logs.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68282753/edit) the question and include the logs which are in terminal, also I suggest you to run app in debug mode. app.run(debug=True).

Comment: @charchit I have tried adding the debug=True in the flask code, it shows me the traceback but I don't really understand. I have also updated my question.

Comment: i think there is a problem in app.run(debug=True) , Might be your device don't support it. Anyway you can remove debug=True and then also you can see the correct error in the terminal where you ran you flask app. You can paste the logs here. or you can use env variables to run app. here's a blog for the same https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if **name**=='**main**':

```
 app.run(debug=True,port=9989,use_reloader=False)
```

- Use above code
- If you are using jupyter notebook for flask app then I will recommend you
  to switch the spyder ,pycharm or Vs code IDE
- Because you can easily debug things in IDE as compare to Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

If you still encounter the same issue try checking open/busy ports.
Here's the command:
**netstat -ab**

If the port number you are supplying 9989/5000 try changing port numbers with any of available port. The same error is generated when the port being provided is not accessible.